# Text to mesh in 2.8

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to convert a text to a mesh in 2.8. I see that in 2.8 the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> command no longer exists, I did find the feature under the "object" tab though.

When I hit the convert command it does not convert, but a pop-up appears showing the command options. It seems that there is no way to apply it to the text.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The conversion is done right away when you use *Object > Convert to > Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*. If you enable *Keep Original* in the last operation panel, the original text object will be kept and a new object is created for the mesh version.

[image: Keep original]

If you disable *Keep Original* the original will be removed and you only have the mesh version in your scene.

[image: Don't keep original]

The outliner indicates the object type with the green icon behind the name.

Comment: After reading your answer I realized that the text I was trying to convert to a mesh was letters that I had made so it was already a mesh. I did, however, apply a re-mesh modifier to clean up the edges I used to make the letters.  ;-)